# Function didn't work because of css - where's the mistake?

Tags: css, r, web-scraping

I am scraping forum user profiles (for research only).

Yesterday while working on the script I constructed 2 versions of a function with slightly different css extracted from Selector Gadget:

F1:

```
prof_info <- function(url1){  
  profile <- jump_to(pgsession, url1)
  page <- html(profile) 
  profile_info <- html_nodes(x = page, css = "dd , dt , #viewprofile span") 
  data_profile <- as.list(html_text(profile_info, trim = TRUE))
  return(data_profile)
}
```

F2:

```
prof_info2 <- function(url1){  
  profile <- jump_to(pgsession, url1)
  page <- html(profile) 
  profile_info <- html_nodes(x = page, css = ".column2 dd , .column2 dt , .profile-details dd , #viewprofile span , .profile-details dt") 
  data_profile <- as.list(html_text(profile_info, trim = TRUE))
  return(data_profile)
}
```

Yesterday I checked both and both worked, only that F2 gave a slightly better output. So today I've been executing the F2 version on my link list of 60000 links for the past 3 hours. Now it returns me this:

```
[[1]]
list()

[[2]]
list()

[[3]]
list()
```

and so on until 60000.

Why did this happen? What is wrong with F2?

Comment: Please include the names of packages you are using (and add the tags if possible). For example, `jump_to` and `html_nodes` are not base R functions.

Comment: Perhaps the HTML or CSS of the page you are scraping has changed. They are under no obligation to keep it the same. Without a reproducible example for the specific page you are working on it's impossible to tell.